# What is the $k$-vector space structure of $\Omega_{C/k}^1(C)$, for $C$ a proper normal curve over $k$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

The definition of the genus of a proper normal curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ is given as follows in my lecture notes:

> **Definition:** Let $C$ be a proper normal curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, then the genus $g$ of $C$ is defined as the dimension of $\Omega_{C/k}^1$ as a $k$-vector space.

$\Omega_{C/k}^1$ is quasi-coherent and, on all open affine $\operatorname{Spec}A\subseteq C$, given by $\Omega_{C/k}^1(\operatorname{Spec}A)=\Omega_{A/k}^1$, the Kähler differential of $A$ as a $k$-Algebra.

---

**Question:** Why is $\Omega_{C/k}^1(C)$ a $k$-vector space, for $C$ a proper normal curve over $k$?

Comment: I am not sure what is bothering you about the definition -- you say that $\Omega^1_{C/k}$ is a coherent sheaf of $k$-algebras, so in particular it is a sheaf of $k$-vector spaces and in particular its global sections form a $k$-vector space.

Comment: @hunter My problem is that, as far as I understand, this applies only to open affine subschemes. So far I only know that a global section is an $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$-module (because $\Omega_{C/k}^1$ is quasi-coherent).

Comment: @test123 But $k\subseteq \mathcal{O}_C(C)$. in fact, if $C$ is connected then $\mathcal{O}_C(C)=k$!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for the comment but how does one see that?

Comment: @test123 I mean, the first comment you should have no trouble understanding. The structure map $C\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ induces a map $k\to\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ which is an inclusion since $k$ is a field. The second statement can be understood algebraically (by noting that $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ is a domain which is finite-dimensional over $k$ since $C$ is proper, but this then implies by the standard theory that $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ is a finite field extension of $k$ and thus equal to $k$) or geometrically (since map $C\to\mathbb{A}^1_k$ has connected proper reduced image and thus must be a point).

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks!